# Problem with routing after installing UI in Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel

In the new Laravel 9 project, after installing the UI, I have a **problem** with the php artisan **route:cache command**. Message appears:

> Unable to prepare route [password/reset] for serialization. Another
> route has already been assigned name [password.request]. Checking
> route:list, no duplicate route.

Everything is fine on the local server, but some routes are not working on the hosting.

Answer (score 0):

Are the names of those route not the same?

By the name I mean the "name" method as follow bellow:

`Route::get('/user', [UserController::class, 'index'])->name('thisMustBeAnUniqueName);`

Answer (score 0):

First find the details of the duplicates

```
php artisan route:list --name=password.request
```

For me this showed

```
+--------+----------+-----------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI             | Name             | Action                                                                 | Middleware                                      |
+--------+----------+-----------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | forgot-password | password.request | Laravel\Fortify\Http\Controllers\PasswordResetLinkController@create    | web                                             |
|        |          |                 |                  |                                                                        | App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated:web |
|        | GET|HEAD | password/reset  | password.request | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm | web                                             |
|        |          |                 |                  |                                                                        | App\Http\Middleware\Cors                        |
+--------+----------+-----------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
```

Which led to the `routes/web.php` file that had the default

`Auth::routes();`

removing this line (I knew the alternate authorisation package was in place)  and re-running

```
php artisan route:cache
```

fixed the conflict.